# Can I get a list of the variables that reference an other in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, variables, pointers, reference

Imagine I have:

```
X = [0,1]
Y = X
Z = Y
```

Is there a function like referenced_by(X) that returns something like `['Y', 'Z']`? And a function like points_to(Y) that returns `'X'`?

I know there is `is` to test whether to objects are the same, I just would like a quick way to get the names though.

Comment: obligatory question: Why?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and no. You can get a list of *global* variables:

```
for name, val in globals().items():
    if val is obj:
        yield name
```

You can also get a list of *local* variables:

```
for name, val in locals().items():
    if val is obj:
        yield name
```

However, you will with this miss all variables in other contexts than local to your function or global to the module. You can find variables in calling contexts with frame-magic, but you won't be able to find anything that is global to other modules, for example.

What you would use this for, I don't know.

You will also not find any attributes that reference the object, but attributes aren't variables so maybe that's OK.

You can get all objects that reference your object though. And that will include the globals and locals for all the functions. But you can't get the name of the variables in that case. You can do

```
>>> import gc
>>> gc.get_referrers(obj)
```

To get a list of all objects referencing the object `obj`. Once again this is pretty useless. :-)

If you want the names you can look up the keys in the cases that the referrer is a dictionary or a stack frame:

```
import gc
import types

def find_ref_names(obj):
    for ref in gc.get_referrers(obj):
        if isinstance(ref, types.FrameType):
            look_in = [ref.f_locals, ref.f_globals]
        elif isinstance(ref, dict):
            look_in = [ref]
        else:
            continue
        for d in look_in:
            for k, v in d.items():
                if v is obj:
                    yield k


def main():
    a = "heybaberiba"
    b = a
    c = b

    print list(find_ref_names(b))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will print:

```
['a', 'c', 'b', 'obj']
```

But as you don't know which context the variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `obj` is defined in, it's yet again pretty useless. As an example move the definition of a to the module-level and you get this result:

```
['c', 'b', 'a', 'obj', 'a', 'a']
```

Where one of these `a` is the global one, and others are copies into local contexts.

As for your second question:

> And a function like points_to(Y) that returns 'X'?

That's the same function. Both `X` and `Y` are just names pointing to the same object, in this case a list. `X` is no different from `Y`, and `Y` does not point to `X`. `Y` points to `[0,1]` and so does `X`.

Comment: +1 This is clearly a better answer than mine and I removed my solution. :)